# Android How to set View's default background-color

Tags: java, android, layout, android-linearlayout, background-color

I'm new to Android and I need help here.

```
animeList.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Why it doesn't affect the layout background? The one in the click event work well. I tried with the TextView and nothing changed. Thanks...

```
package com.animeworld.tenshi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AnimeCategoryActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anime_category);

        ArrayList<Anime> animes = new ArrayList<>();
        Anime[] listOfAnime = Anime.animes;
        for(Anime loa : listOfAnime) {
            animes.add(loa);
        }
        LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_anime_category);
        for(Anime anime : animes) {
            final LinearLayout animeList = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams animeListLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            animeListLayout.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 5);
            animeList.setLayoutParams(animeListLayout);
            animeList.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            animeList.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch(event.getAction())
                    {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            animeList.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7CCAFA"));
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            animeList.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            ImageView animeListImg = new ImageView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams animeListImgLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 300);
            animeListImgLayout.setMargins(0, 0, 5, 0);
            animeListImg.setLayoutParams(animeListImgLayout);

            TextView animeListDesc = new TextView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams animeListDescLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            animeListDesc.setLayoutParams(animeListDescLayout);
            animeListDesc.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            animeListDesc.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            animeListDesc.setTextSize(18);

            animeList.addView(animeListImg);
            animeList.addView(animeListDesc);
            animeListImg.setImageResource(anime.getImageResourceId());
            animeListDesc.setText(anime.getName());
            mainLayout.addView(animeList);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dynamically adding your layout inside the `"mainLayout"` container. So you have to set background color to your parent view / container view.